# How to batch sql calls using servicestack

Tags: c#, sqlite, ormlite-servicestack

I have an application that is writing records almost continuously in response to a system event.  I am using C# ServiceStack Ormlite.  I wonder if there is an easy way to batch these inserts such that instead of writing each one at a time, it would collect X many and then write in one transaction.  This would reduce the disk usage and speed up the app (other things are going on).

Win 10, VS2019 C# Sqlite

Comment: Probably could, the thing about batching though is that you might be at risk of losing events if something goes wrong (power loss; crash etc).  Is that a requirement for you?

Comment: Considered that and that would be acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InsertAll()` which is more efficient than individual `Insert()` statements as it executes all inserts within a single implicit transaction and reuses the same parameterized insert statement for each record, but it's not as efficient as constructing a single SQL statement and sending it to the RDBMS with something like:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    sb.Append(db.ToInsertStatement(row)).AppendLine(";");
}
db.ExecuteSql(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use structured datatype i.e. Table datatype for bulk insert

and in stored procedure 
you can

```
insert into table (some columns) 
select some columns 
from @structured_variable (table variable)
```